# ¿Cómo hago para calcular el promedio de esta matriz?, y además, ¿cómo la almaceno en la última posición de cada fila?

Tags: c++, array, algoritmos, matrices

Esto es lo que llevo, ya luego de aquí intenté diversos códigos para sacar promedio, pero no encuentro por Internet una solución clara a esto.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int notas [5][5], prom;
int f, c, es = 1, suma = 0;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    for (f = 0; f < 5; f++) {
        printf("\n\tESTUDIANTE %d:  ",f+1);

        for (c = 0; c < 4; c++) {
            printf("\nIndique la nota de la asignatura %d:  ", c+1);
            scanf("%d", &notas [f][c]);
            es++;
        }
    }

    for (f = 0; f < 5; f++);
    {
        for (c = 0; c < 5; c++);
        {
            suma+= notas[f][c];
        };
    };
```

Comment: Especifica el lenguaje de programacion

Comment: Es c++, utilizo el compilador Zinjal

Comment: A ver quieres hallar el promedio por cada fila y en la última columna de esa fila poner el promedio de esa fila,  o hallar el promedio completo de toda la matriz

Answer (score 0):

Si no me equivoco, tendrías que cambiar el segundo **for** para que quedara algo, tal que:

```cpp
for (c = 0; c < 5; c++)
{
    printf("\nIndique la nota de la asignatura %d:  ", c+1);
    scanf("%d", &notas [f][c]);
    es++;
}
```

Cambiando `c < 4` por `c < 5` ,ya que tienes una matriz `5 x 5`.

Y por otro lado, el promedio de las materias por cada estudiante sería:

```cpp
for (f = 0; f < 5; f++);
{
   prom = 0;
    for (c = 0; c < 5; c++);
    {
        prom += notas[f][c];
    };

    prom = prom / 5; // Dividido por la cantidad de materias.
    printf("\n El promedio del estudiante %d es %d:  ", f, prom);
};
```

Edit: Si quieres almacenar las notas en la ultima posición de cada fila, debes tener el ultimo **for** algo, tal que:

```cpp
suma = 0;
for (f = 0; f < 5; f++);
{
    prom = 0;
    for (c = 0; c < 4; c++);
    {
        prom += notas[f][c];
    };
    prom = prom / 4; // Dividido por la cantidad de materias.

    notas[f][5] = prom;
    suma += prom; // Sumamos el promedio de cada estudiante
};
suma = suma / 5; // dividimos por la cantidad de estudiantes
printf("\n El promedio de la clase es: %d:  ", suma);
```